# Comparing times/dates with the iphone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone, datetime, nsdate

I am new to the whole iPhone SDK and objective C, but have managed to get three times, two pulled from RSS feed, and one from the iphone.
I currently have: sunrise, sunset and current time set like:

```
    6:51 am //Sunrise
    7:36 pm //Sunset
    11:34 AM //Current time
```

I am trying to work out the best approach to find out if its day or night?
Any help on this welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to create NSDate objects from your dates.

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string
```

In [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you have:
`earlierDate`, `laterDate` and `compare` that you can use.

For day time you want:

> currentTime >= sunrise && < sunset

for night time you want:

> currentTime >= sunset && < sunrise

Pseudo code :)